# Need help in creating custom objectclasses and attributetypes in openldap

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am trying to create an custom attribute in openldap. For which i am suppose to create an objectclasses. Here my ldif file below.

## Ldif File Content

```
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: attributetypes

attributetypes:( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.1.100 NAME 'x-my-photo1' DESC 'a user photo' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 SINGLE-VALUE )

add:objectclasses
objectclasses:(1.1.2.2.6 NAME 'x-photoObject1' DESC 'mixin x-my-photo' SUP top  STRUCTURAL MAY x-my-photo)
```

## This is the output log.

```
MOD dn="cn=schema,cn=config"
MOD attr=attributetypes objectclasses
RESULT tag=103 err=21 text=attributetypes: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

There seems to be an error which i am not able to figure out.

At the end I should be able to see my custom object while creating new entry.